# Last and next gateway not showing correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Hi I have following query, it's a query that shows the next gateway info of 1 project.
But I want to join this as a CTE to another query but I need to change this [Gateway].[ProjectFk]=744 because the 744 is only for 1 line, every line has a different ProjectFk, can I give a param to a CTE?

```
SELECT [Gateway].[ProjectFk],[GatewayTitle].[Title],[Gat_Date],[GatewayStatus].[Title]
FROM [LocalGTPDatabase].[dbo].[Gateway]
LEFT JOIN [LocalGTPDatabase].[dbo].[GatewayTitle] ON [GatewayTitle].[ID]=[Gateway].[Gat_TitleFk]
LEFT JOIN [LocalGTPDatabase].[dbo].[GatewayStatus] ON [GatewayStatus].[ID]=[Gateway].[Gat_StatusFk]
LEFT JOIN [LocalGTPDatabase].[dbo].[Project] ON [Project].[ID]=[Gateway].[ProjectFk]
WHERE [GatewayStatus].[Title]='Target' and [Gateway].[ProjectFk]=744
order by CONVERT(DATETIME, CASE WHEN ISDATE([Gat_Date]) = 1 THEN [Gat_Date] END) asc
```

but when I combine this query with the other info it's not showing the data, it shows it sometimes but not as much as I would like, I want to get all my projects with their gateways:

```
  WITH

 /****** Next Gateway  ******/
MyCTE10 (ProjectFk, nextGatTitle, nextGatDate, nextGatStatus)as
(SELECT TOP 1 [Gateway].[ProjectFk],[GatewayTitle].[Title],[Gat_Date],[GatewayStatus].[Title]
FROM [LocalGTPDatabase].[dbo].[Gateway]
LEFT JOIN [LocalGTPDatabase].[dbo].[GatewayTitle] ON [GatewayTitle].[ID]=[Gateway].[Gat_TitleFk]
LEFT JOIN [LocalGTPDatabase].[dbo].[GatewayStatus] ON [GatewayStatus].[ID]=[Gateway].[Gat_StatusFk]
LEFT JOIN [LocalGTPDatabase].[dbo].[Project] ON [Project].[ID]=[Gateway].[ProjectFk]
WHERE [GatewayStatus].[Title]='Target'
order by CONVERT(DATETIME, CASE WHEN ISDATE([Gat_Date]) = 1 THEN [Gat_Date] END) asc ) ,

    /****** Get all the links between projects and teams ******/
SELECT [LinkProject-Area].[ID] as [Link_ID],[LinkProject-Area].[ProjectFk] as [Project_ID],[Project].[GTDSnr]    as [Proj_No],[Project].[Title]   
, [MyCTE10].[nextGatTitle] as [Next Gateway], [MyCTE10].[nextGatDate] as [Next Gateway Date],     [MyCTE10].[nextGatStatus] as [Next Gateway Status]
FROM [LocalGTPDatabase].[dbo].[LinkProject-Area]
LEFT JOIN [MyCTE10] ON [MyCTE10].ProjectFk = [LinkProject-Area].[ProjectFk]
WHERE [Project].[ID]>0
order by [Proj_No],[hasLead] desc
```

What am I doing wrong? is it because of the limit one but how do I overcome this problem?
I'm selecting all the gateways of the project in my CTE and then I just collect the first one, when I do this separatly I can add a WHERE [ProjectFk] and I get all the gateways for that project and If I limit it I can get the one I need, but because I'm getting all my projects I need to remove the where projectFk=something from that part of the query and just join it on the projectFk, but now it's not only showing 2 dates 1 for next gateway and 1 for last gateway because of the limit, ...

**Solved it: I don't think you can use CTE for this but  you have to use a user defined function/ put the first query in a function where projectFk is a parameter:
And then join them like this:
     OUTER APPLY
     dbo.LastGatewayAll([LinkProject-Area].[ProjectFk]) AS subLastGateWays
this will give you the possibility to get the data like this:
    subLastGateWays.[gateway] as [Last GW],subLastGateWays.[status] as [Last GW Status],subLastGateWays.[Gat_Date] as [Last GW Date]
I hope this post became a bit clearer on what I was trying to do...**

Comment: your query is too huge to analyse i think. Can you put only relevant part of query which you think doesnt work?

Comment: i can see difference that above query is not using Top clause and below query is not using Top clause. What is "MyCTE10 (ProjectFk, nextGatTitle, nextGatDate, nextGatStatus)as" I really cant understand what are you doing. I am sorry about it.

Comment: better? or still not precise enough?

Comment: The first query is a seperate query to get the next gateway for 1 project, in the query that follows I try to join that query with the query I already had to collect project data, this is MyCTE10. but because of the limit I'm making mistakes....

Comment: you are missing this condition in lower query [Gateway].[ProjectFk]=744

Comment: But this should be a different number for everz line item I retrieve, so the first could be 744 etc, that|s why I join the CTE and the other querz with the projectFk